# How to read numbers on text files using turbo c++ 4.0?

Tags: text-files, turbo-c++

I am a beginner in programming and I am trying to make a code that reads 2 numbers from a file and then displays it in the output window on turbo c++.
My code only reads the first number and produces incorrect output for the second number.

```
 #include<iostream.h>
 #include<fstream.h>
 #include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    int x, y;
    clrscr();
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;
    inFile.open("prac.txt");

    while(!inFile.eof())
    inFile >> x >> y;
    cout << x << " " << y;

    inFile.close();

}
```

Comment: can you tell us more about "incorrect"? include the first 3-4 lines of the file and also the output.

Comment: what's the incorrect output for the second number you're seeing? How have the two numbers been written into prac.txt, is there maybe a line feed (LF) between them?

Comment: I'd discourage using Turbo C++ unless you are specifically targeting ancient platforms, it's an outdated toolchain (indeed conio.h is a non-standard header).There are multiple valid alternatives (including MSVC2015 community edition, which is free)

Comment: The file contains the numbers: 
2 3
Output :
2 0
Output when called as a function:
2 -28903
the output is also very different if I call it as a function which is what I was supposed to do I was just using it in main to see what happens. Sorry but our teacher wanted us to learn in Turbo c++ so I don't really have choice.

Comment: @Max♦ Sorry I really am just a beginner so I don't know anything about line feed. The only thing I can tell you is that the numbers 2 3 is at the same line  separated by a space.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read data from files in Turbo c++ 4.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34489267/how-to-read-data-from-files-in-turbo-c-4-0)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<fstream.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main() {
  clrscr();
  ifstream inFile;
  inFile.open("prac.txt");
  while(!inFile.eof()) {
    int num;
    inFile>>num;
    cout<<num<<" ";
  }
  inFile.close();
}
```