# How to read data from files in Turbo c++ 4.0?

Tags: c++, text-files, turbo-c++

I am a beginner in programming and I am trying to make a code that reads 2 numbers from a file and then 
displays it in the output window on turbo c++. My code only reads the first number and produces incorrect output
 for the second number.

```
 #include<iostream.h>
 #include<fstream.h>
 #include<conio.h>

void main()
{
  int x, y;
  clrscr();
  ifstream inFile;
  ofstream outFile;
  inFile.open("prac.txt");

  while(!inFile.eof())
  inFile >> x >> y;
  cout << x << " " << y;

  inFile.close();

 }
```

The file contains the numbers: `2` `3`

Output : `2` `0`

Output when called as a function: `2` `-28903` which is very different if I call it as a function compared when its in main  which is what I was supposed to be doing
 I was just using it in main to see what happens.

Sorry, but our teacher wanted us to learn in Turbo c++ so I don't 
really have choice with the compiler.

Comment: do not use Turbo C++, it's not a C++ compiler because it's decades older than the first C+ standard. Many non-standart things you can see in the above code: `std` namespace, `void main(), `iostream.h`...

Comment: Also, don't post the same question twice.

Answer (score 1):

The `std::cout` should be inside the while loop:

```
while(!inFile.eof()){
     inFile >> x >> y;
     cout << x << " " << y;
}
```

Comment: what is inside the file ? are you sure that there is a space between 2 and 3 ?

Comment: only the numbers which is:  2 3 . Yes, I am sure. I also tried placing 3 on the next line but I still get 2 0 as output.

Comment: It is plausible that the Turbo C++ is so old that it doesn't work correctly?

Comment: Maybe but I don't think our professor would force us to use this if there's a possibility that it won't work properly.

Comment: there's no `std` in Turbo C++

Comment: @Euphemia: Your professor shouldn't be counted on, and the fact that he is using Turbo C++ is sufficient proof. That compiler doesn't even implement the 1998 standard. It _literally_ is a compiler from a previous century.

Answer (score 0):

Try using infile>>x>>y inside the while loop condition like this

```
while(infile>>x>>y)
```

then use the cout statement in the loop.